# How can I design this layout in android?

Tags: android

[How to add this, a clickable image inside edittext and also a button with EditText, how can I design this using android?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wu9tZ.jpg)

Comment: is that a search bar?

Comment: Use RelativeLayout. Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_back_navigation" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/clickableImageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_back_navigation" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="ADD" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:text="ADD"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </LinearLayout>
```